# How can save a text file in a folder created on an FTP server?

Tags: asp.net

I have created an application which creates a folder on an FTP server when clicking on a button.

Now I need to store some text files to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well read about how to create file using your language, and show us the code where you get error to help further.

Comment: You have to create a folder set  its read and write permissions and create you folder there otherwise you will get permission exception

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind you have to create a folder and set permission for read and write on the server then you can create a folder in which you can create any file type.

```
protected void Submit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
`enter code here`  using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true))
 {
  _testData.WriteLine("this is how you will create a file"); // Write the file.
 }         
}
```

or

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), TextBox1.Text);
```